# Is it recommended to use Docker with AWS Elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deciding how to deploy my Nodejs API to AWS Elastic beanstalk. I have 2 options: deploy it as a normal nodejs service or deploy the api dockerized.

In which situations is it more recomendable to use docker over a normal nodejs service? (Giving the fact that I will use Elastic beanstalk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running your NodeJS as a Docker container in Elastic Beanstalk will definitely give you more control over your application.

However, it depends how much time you want to invest. Their maybe slightly more time in deploying with Docker, especially if you haven't used it before.

Answer (score 0):

> In which situations is it more recomendable to use docker over a
>   normal nodejs service? (Giving the fact that I will use Elastic
>   beanstalk)

First, if you really interested to run docker container in AWS, then [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) is what you need to run your application, lot of reason to run docker in ECS over elastic beanstalk

- Serverless ([faragate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/))
- Scaling
- Container management
- Ci/CD with code deploy etc

> Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) is a fully managed container orchestration service. Customers such as Duolingo, Samsung, GE, and Cook Pad use ECS to run their most sensitive and mission-critical applications because of its security, reliability, and scalability.

[AWS ECS getting-started](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/getting-started/)

docker is recommended if you manage multiple environments in short as its not simple question to answer but better to go with Docker as this what future deman,  if you just want to want to run dev like environment then elastic beanstalk is fine.